# Rxjava2 flowable not firing onComplete

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

Here is the code

```
    private fun setUpDistrictSpinner() {
    commonRepo.getAllDistricts()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap { list -> Flowable.fromIterable(list) }
            .map { district ->
                districtNameList.add(district.district_name)
                district
            }.subscribe(object:Subscriber<District>{
        override fun onComplete() {
            labSelectionInterface.loadDistricts(districtNameList)
            Timber.d("district List loaded total " + districtList.size)
        }

        override fun onError(t: Throwable?) {
            t!!.printStackTrace()
        }

        override fun onNext(t: District) {
            districtList.add(t)
        }

        override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription) {
            s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE)
        }
    })

}
```

onNext is firing but onComplete will not fire. There is also no error message. I am loading list of district into a spinner. Using Room database and Kotlin 
This is where I get the Flowable

```
    fun getAllDistricts(): Flowable<List<District>> {
    Timber.d("District list accessed")
    return appDatabase.districtDao().getAllDistricts()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

}
```

Comment: are you triggering onComplete? What does getAllDistricts look like

Comment: what is appDatabase.districtDao().getAllDistricts()?

Comment: @Query("SELECT * from districts")
    fun getAllDistricts(): Flowable<List<District>>
Its Room query which return flowable

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Flowable` returned by Room never completes. It allows you to receive update upon database modifications.

> Here’s how the Flowable behaves:
>
> 1. When there is no user in the database and the query returns no rows, the Flowable will not emit, neither onNext, nor onError.
> 2. When there is a user in the database, the Flowable will trigger onNext.
> 3. Every time the user data is updated, the Flowable object will emit automatically, allowing you to update the UI based on the latest data.

If you want to receive `onComplete` event, switch to `Maybe`. You should read this [article](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757).